# Eclipse + JSF + Spring Form = CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-mvc

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" <-- CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB
        xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/tags"> <--  CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB
<ui:composition template="../../templates/master-page.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">Home</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="parentSelected">Restaurante</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="childSelected">Adicionar</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        bla
        ${teste}
        ${teste2}
        <h:button value="BLA" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Good night I have a problem in relation to use Spring Form taglib to create my form with spring on a page. xhtml that uses jsf, so that the spring form taglib from not being recognized.

Comment: You're clearly using Eclipse. This error message key which is being displayed plain text instead of being localized, is known as one of the Eclipse localization bugs. As to the concrete problem, does it work if you ignore the error and deploy and run the project?

Answer (score 0):

You should have spring-servlet.jar in your class path, form taglib is present inside the META-INF in this very jar.

Comment: Yes... In my opinion is the easiest way to put the spring-servlet.jar into the WebContent\WEB-INF\lib folder

Comment: I have the spring-servlet.jar classpth included in my application, the more it is not even recognized.